# SVN repo and eclipse projects

Tags: svn, subclipse

Ok, so I'll try to explain this as best I can.  We have recently migrated a java project across to SVN from MKS.  The problem we are having is that once we have synced down the file system and built the packages (using Ant) for import into Eclipse, the link between the files in the projects and the file system is lost, so we cannot submit changes to a project file through Subclipse as the repo holds the file system.

Does anyone know of a way the Subclipse can import a file system and build the projects, maintaining the link?

There was a reason why we don't just add the built projects, but it escapes me right now.  If I remember I will update the question.

I hope I have explained this well enough for someone to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that your build script is deleting the .svn folder in your working copy so this breaks the Subversion working copy.  I would recommend using Subclipse 1.8.x which uses Subversion 1.7.x.  As of Subversion 1.7.x there is only a single .svn folder in the root of your working copy.  Earlier versions had a .svn folder in every managed folder.